# GCC Compiler, compile app for lower version of GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, cross-compiling

I'm developing C++ application on Debian machine with installed GCC 6.3.0 x64 architecture, but the application would run on Centos with GCC 4.4.7 x86.

How do I compile my app for the target environment? Is the only way to do that is to install GCC 4.4.7 on my host machine?

Comment: You can compile/run it online - https://wandbox.org/  (for example)

Comment: @SChepurin I think that's missing the point a little!

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit  - yes, didn't notice x86 vs x64.

Comment: Architecture is irrelevant. Online compilers don't give you an executable you can run.

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit - right, but the only reasonable way (in my point of view) would be to develop code using GCC 4.4.7 and then build the executable  under target environment. All the other options are too "fragile".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit some do, by providing you with editable command line of compilation ([example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/93a402a1093f518e)), but not all support many versions of the compiler. E.g. Coliru appears to only have g++ 4.9.2, 5.1.0, 5.2.0 and 8.2.0.

Comment: @Ruslan: Hah, I'd never thought of "exporting" executables from Coliru like that.

Answer (score 3):

You can build with your GCC 6.3, but you should use the `-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0` option to use the older ABI to be compatible with GCC older than 4.9. Otherwise it will not run properly on the target system.

To be absolutely sure of compatibility, you can indeed use the toolchain of the target system. You don't need to install it on your machine directly though. You can compile in a virtual machine running the older distro, or use docker (or some other container system).

Comment: I'd expand this a bit. On Linux you _usually_ want to compile with the same toolchain as the target (ideally _on_ the target) but yes GCC is friendly about compatibility and provides this flag to ensure it.

Comment: @eerorika do you mean that this flag would make my app compatible with the target GCC

Comment: @MahmoudEmam I am talking to eerorika

Comment: @MahmoudEmam it should make it compatible, yes.

Comment: `_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI` alone won't help: it's not only this particular quirk of the ABI which changes. A program compiled with g++ 6 will require `GLIBCXX_3.4.22` in `libstdc++.so.6`, while g++ 4.4.7 only provides `libstdc++.so.6` with `GLIBCXX_3.4.13` (specific version numbers were taken from [this page](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/abi.html)). If you don't install a newer `libstdc++.so` on the target system, you'll get errors like ``version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found`` from the dynamic linker.